# for loop with isset() != null - why?

Tags: php

```
for($i=0; isset($_POST['key_str'][$i]) != null; $i++)
{
    // some php here
}
```

I've inherited some legacy code at work and I've found above for() loop in several places. I've been writing PHP, Javascript and Python for years now and have never seen anything like this. My gut tells me this is the person who wrote this legacy code came from a different language.  And may have not been very experienced.

Questions:

1) Does `isset($_POST['key_str'][$i])` perform better than `count($_POST['key_str'])`?

2) Does this resemble syntax that you'd typically find in another language? If so, which language?

Comment: From php.net `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise. `

Comment: I understand isset(). What doesn't make sense to me is why it is inside a for() loop.

Comment: `What doesn't make sense to me is why it is inside a for() loop.` Welcome to the wonderful world of Legacy Code ! :D

Comment: I've been developing in PHP for more than a decade and have never seen anything like this.  It makes me cringe but it works so I'm leaving it in.  Finding weird stuff like this everywhere.

Comment: @d_bubb it's a good question, and i don't have any idea.... :(

Comment: Meh I'd make the change @b_dubb just to save the headache of the next coder who comes across it

Comment: `$_POST['key_str'][$i]` might be set but it might be a string instead of an array. I would wrap the for loop in a conditional that tests for correct var type (array) and a count() of > 0.  This just looks extremely problematic and well ... wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[isset()](http://php.net/isset) is a language construct that returns a boolean, thus it can never be `null`. However, the [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) uses the *equal* operator (`==`) rather than the *identical* operator (`===`) thus [type juggling applies](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types):

```
Type of Operand 1   Type of Operand 2   Result
bool or null        anything            Convert both sides to bool
```

… and `null` [casts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) to boolean `false` so:

```
true  != null → true  != false → true
false != null → false != false → false
```

Thus the loop is equivalent to:

```
for($i=0; isset($_POST['key_str'][$i]); $i++){}
```

In other words, `!= null` is redundant and harms readability.

Now, square brackets are used to read an array element by key or a string byte by offset. Since `$_POST` is an external variable the loop can actually do both—I presume the former was intended. Without further context it's impossible to say what it's meant to accomplish or how to rewrite it but I suspect it's a convoluted alternative to `foreach()`.

So to answer your questions:

1. It's irrelevant. They do entirely different things.
2. This is opinion-based (to me, it's the syntax of someone who's not familiar with programming in general.)

Answer (score 3):

Inside isset, `$i` (which is incremented in the loop) is used in this expression. `$_POST['key_str'][$i]`, which is part of the check.

So basically, `$_POST['key_str']` is expected to be an array, and this loop will loop over all items in that array.

If you like, you could use `count()`, or replace the whole thing with a `foreach` loop, although that may result in a warning if `$_POST['key_str']` is not set at all or is not an array. `isset` is a very easy way to get around that, because it handles all those situations and will return false, so the loop will simply not be entered in that scenario.

Comment: does that perform better than count($_POST['key_str']) ?

Comment: I don't know about performance (and I wouldn't worry about that unless you expect this array to contain thousands of items). But I do think there is a bit of a safeguard, because the current loop will still 'work' if that post variable is not set or is not an array, while a foreach loop or using count would result in a warning.

Comment: `foreach()` is much faster than a `for()` and I heavily suspect a `for()` is far faster than: accessing an array index->checking if it's set->checking the value isn't null

Comment: So ... no ... it is not better performing than `count($arr) > 0`?

Comment: @GolezTrol "isset() is a very easy way to get around that, because it handles all those situations and will return false, so the loop will simply not be entered in that scenario". At this point it looks like there may be a performance hit using this method but it would save a couple lines of code/conditional.  I'm all about better performing code as this array may well have thousands of vars inside it.

Comment: I would go for readable over fast any time, except when performance is really key. But I think isset is quite fast, and to do it differently, you may have to do multiple checks. If you want it faster, you'd have to check if it's an array _and_ get the count outside of the loop. And even then, what will take longer: posting those items from the client to the server, or executing `isset` a couple of times? Is optimization necessary? Anyway, the goal of my answer was to explain the code, and to point out possible pitfalls when changing it. I didn't mean to defend it as being a good solution. :-)